# How can I get the wrapped input from an ion-input in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'd like to attach an `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` to an `ion-input`, but in **Ionic2** `ion-input` wraps the `<input>` element and I can't figure out how to get access to it.

I've tried creating a directive and using the passed in `ElementRef`

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[location-picker]'
})

export class LocationPicker {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {    
        console.log(el.nativeElement);    
    }
}
```

but `nativeElement` returns the wrapped input.

```
<ion-input location-picker="">
    <input class="text-input ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="" aria-labelledby="lbl-6" location-picker="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</ion-input>
```

I've also tried creating a custom component similar to [this](http://blog.appweplay.com/2016/02/google-autocomplete-with-ionic2.html) and switching `Searchbar` to `TextInput`, but `TextInput doesn't have`.inputElement`.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, are you able to provide complete code of how you implemented google places Autocomplete with ionic 2 ? :). thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this is what you're looking for (don't know Ionic)

```
<ion-input location-picker="">
    <input #myInput class="text-input ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="" aria-labelledby="lbl-6" location-picker="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off">
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
    <!--template bindings={}-->
</ion-input>
```

```
@ViewChild('myInput') input; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
}
```

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: Unfortunately that's just the output of `console.log(el.nativeElement);` so I can't edit it in that way. I've edited my question to make it more clear. Thank you though!

Comment: What about `this.nativeElement.querySelector('input')`?

Comment: Might be necessary to be moved to `ngAfterViewInit()` to give Angular time to finish building the view.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question. A combination of the accepted answer and the comments below it seemed to solve it for me.

Adding this function to my Directive seemed to do it. I'm using Typescript and 
the typings definition for googlemaps found here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    var input: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>this._el.querySelector("input");
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
      var place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.invokeEvent(place);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Search your city</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="placeAutofill" id="googlePlaces" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

And in my code:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
   // Google Places API auto complete
   let input = document.getElementById('googlePlaces').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
   let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {types: ['geocode']});
   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
     // retrieve the place object for your use
     let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   });
}
```

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to port this code to directive. If you have suggestions, let me know!